# Is there a tool to document .net code across multiple solutions?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sharepoint, tfs, documentation

We are looking to implement a documentation solution that would allow us to search all of our solutions and projects for potential reusable code.  An example would be services.  If we create a handful of WCF services we want the other developers to be able to search the available services and view the documentation of that service to see if it would fit their needs.

Currently we are using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate as well as TFS 2012 and SharePoint 2013.

I have looked into the popular documenting tools such as GhostDoc Pro and Sandcastle, but they seem to be only geared toward handling a single solution.
Now all the documentation could be built for all the solutions and each solutions has it's own documentation web page, but how would you leverage some easy to use method to search across all solutions documentation?  We also looked into loading the sites created by GhostDoc and Sandcastle into SharePoint for a central searchable location, but this is cumbersome as SharePoint only allows you to load one file at a time.

Essentially our end goal is the have a company wide maintainable documentation solution that organizes all documentation and allows for searching across all documentation.

I feel like this has to be something that has been done before, but I am unable to find any existing solutions to this.

**edit for more info:**

Ideally we would want something similar if not exactly what sandcastle and ghostdoc build now. A document that allows you to easily few a class and it's members. The tool would be getting its information from XML documentation. Not having to build the docs ourselves would be ideal. That is why a tool like sandcastle is nice. As long as you have worthwhile XML documentation it will build a nice help file very easily

Comment: Presumably you mean something other than Microsoft Word, or a SharePoint list or Wiki? Where would the documentation tool get its information from?

Comment: Sandcastle or Visual Studio (not sure which one) builds a pre-xml, that sandcastle finally transforms into a help file (or whatever options available). What if you merge those XML files manually? My 2 cents, haven't used sandcastle for a while.

Comment: Ideally we would want something similar if not exactly what sandcastle and ghostdoc build now.  A document that allows you to easily view a class and it's members.  The tool would be getting its information from XML documentation.  Not having to build the docs ourselves would be ideal.  That is why a tool like sandcastle is nice.  As long as you have worthwhile XML documentation it will build a nice help file very easily.  Added this to original question as well.

Comment: You could have one sandcastle helpfile builder project with multiple document sources I.e. projects/solutions? Everytime you create a new soljtion or project remeber to add it to sandcastle project? This would take a considerable amount to compile so maybe a nightly build in TFS.  U may end up with multiple/repetitive documentation if its done at solution level so project level maybe better. U could compile SHFB as a .chm to use the search functionality within it. Never used html output format. This relies on your code being well documented. GIGO.

Comment: If you use the XML documentation - there's no way "out of the box" to generate documentation that resolves conflicts between solutions. This is the Microsoft "by definition" behavior. Using sancastle or other tools might work, however I didn't get it to work good enough. Main problem was that if solution A documented a class that solution B has, only one of the documentations would show.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Generate HTML documentation with Sandcastle.
- Put it on some shared folder.
- Have every user index it with Copernic Desktop Search Professional?